# How can i count how much data have already sent to server by HttpURLConnection?

Tags: java, android

I sent a `byte[]` to server. I can count `byte[]` size which i am going to send, but how can i get size of `byte[]` which have already sent? I want implement it in order to show to user a `progressBar` in % .

Here is the my code :

```
public static JSONObject sentJsonToServer(final URL url, final byte[] data, final String newValue) {

    ExecutorService ex = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    Future<JSONObject> objectFuture = ex.submit(new Callable<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public JSONObject call() throws Exception {

            BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

            try {

                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", newValue);
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                urlConnection.connect();
                bos = new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
                bos.write(data);
                bos.flush();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (bos != null) {
                        bos.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

//              returns POST request
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                return getJSONFromUrl(urlConnection);
            } else {
                throw new NullPointerException();
            }
        }
    });

    JSONObject responseJson = null;

    try {
        responseJson = objectFuture.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("LAST JSOOOOOOOOOOON!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! " + responseJson);

    return responseJson;
}
```

I try implement smth like `ProgressListener()` but without succes(

**How i can make it?**

Comment: As you're writing the data in one go, and as `HttpURLConnection` will buffer all the data anyway so it can prefix a Content-length header, the answer is that you can't. NB `setDoOutput(true)` sets the request method to POST, and `setDoInput(true)` is the default.

Comment: @EJP Sorry but i didn't understand exactly. Would you clear up please? You mean it is not necessary set `setDoOutput(true)`?